# For which numbers $c$ is there a number $x$ such that $f(cx)=f(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

This is one exercise in Spivak's book that is bugging me for a while, first I thought that $c=1$, but there's a hint:

> There are a lot more than you might think at first glance.

And here I'm stuck, yesterday I was studying complex numbers and then I thought I could use also $c=i^2$ and also $c=i^{\text{ even number}}$ but when evaluated, the result would be always the same, then I guess the reasoning is not valid. In despair, I even thought about $c=1^{n}$ where $n\in\{x:x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ but it would be the same number after all. I'm clueless on this and I'm aware that the answer may be something deeply stupid and trivial, but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT:** The mentioned exercise print:

---

[image]

Comment: What's $f$ here?

Comment: I guess it's a function. Not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: Given a number $c$, there exists a number $x$ means you just need $x=0$?

Comment: Which exercise is this? I think there's something I'm not understanding.

Comment: One can cheat and use $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ to defeat the fact that $(c)(0)=0$. But maybe the question is not exactly as quoted.

Comment: @JavierBadia [Look](http://imgur.com/nQHYEag).

Comment: Well with the last link, it seems clear every $c$ is a solution, with $x=0$.

Comment: The qeustion made absolutely no sense without the information that $f$ is the function $f(x) = 1/(1+x)$; did you really expect anyone to understand it?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I don't know. I just posted as is in the book.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira With your edit, note that the question is not phrased as asking for what value of $c$ does $f(cx) = f(x)$. However, it is asking you, for what values of $c$, does there exist an $x^*$ such that $f(cx^*) = f(x^*)$.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR doesnt look like the answer would be different for other functions, as long as 0 is in the domain. Though the OP should have been more faithful in reproducing the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to find the values of $c$ such that $f(cx)=f(x)$ for some $x$. Well write out what this means: it means that

$$\dfrac{1}{1+cx} = \dfrac{1}{1+x}$$

Rearranging gives

$$cx=x$$

**CAUTION!** The temptation here is to divide through by $x$, in which case the only solution is $c=1$. But you need to find the values of $c$ for which **some** value of $x$ satisfies the equation. So what else might you be able to have?

When can you *not* divide through by $x$? Why can't you? What implications does this have for your equation? In this case, which values of $c$ still satisfy the equation?